# Adding TypeScript ambient declarations only to specific files (like *.spec.ts)

Tags: typescript, jestjs, typescript-typings, tsconfig

My Jest `setupTests` file defines a number of global identifiers (like `global.sinon = sinon`, but typing them in ambient declarations applies to all files, not just the `*.spec.ts` where the `setupTests` file is included. Previously I've solved this by having a separate `tsconfig.json` file for the `tests` directory, but that is not possible if the test and non-test files are in the same directory. Is there any way to have ambient declarations that only apply to a specific file name pattern? Something like this:

```
declare module "*.spec.ts" {
    // declarations here
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you still have two tsconfigs and play around with the `include` `exclude` in them to get the apropriate files included/excluded ?https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot solve this problem by doing this:

```
declare module "*.spec.ts" {
  /* ... */
}
```

because that's how you describe the *contents* of all `*.spec.ts` files, not the environment in which they executed.

It's best if you can separate your source code from tests and use two separate `tsconfig.json` files. If you must have your source code and tests mixed, the only option that comes to mind is creating a declaration file *outside* of your included files and importing it manually in every test file. For example, you could create a directory called `environment` in the root of your project and put a `test.d.ts` file there.

**`./environment/test.d.ts`**

```
declare const foo: string;
```

Now, every test that depends on the global `foo` will need to reference `environment/test.d.ts`.

**`./path/to/foo.spec.ts`**

```
import '../environment/test';

console.log(foo);
```

This is cumbersome, but I haven't found a better way to serve different globals for different files. Usually, people just pollute their global namespace with all globals they might have (Node, browser, tests).